# How to show different data with HTML5 and jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I need a horizontal menu with four "click"-tabs. When I click on one it should show a table below the menu (see jsFidle: http://jsfiddle.net/SCKhf/576/). When I click on an other button it shows an other table, like in the jsFiddle.

I tried to put this into my homepage, but it does not work. It seems that the jQuery code has no function for any reason. I tried to implement the jQuery code in different ways (clear text in header / link to a js-file). Nothing works.

You can download the HTML5 homepage here. I added the fiddle, but it does not work: http://ge.tt/2itz9FC1/v/0?c (modified, 4 MB)

And here is a picture of my idea: http://justpic.info/images1/79be/example.jpg

Here is the code which is working in jsFiddle but NOT working when putting all the stuff into the homepage:

```
var open = $('.open'),
a = $('ul').find('a');

console.log(a.hasClass('active'));

open.click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var $this = $(this),
    speed = 0;
if($this.hasClass('active') === true) {
    $this.removeClass('active').next('.box').slideUp(speed);
} else if(a.hasClass('active') === false) {
    $this.addClass('active').next('.box').slideDown(speed);
} else {
    a.removeClass('active').next('.box').slideUp(speed);
    $this.addClass('active').next('.box').delay(speed).slideDown(speed);
}
});
```

Comment: I now have no idea what this all means - the fiddle shows a table, your graphic shows something else, i really don't understand what you want to do. Can you do a graphic for each click?

Comment: Sorry, here is a new graphic: http://justpic.info/images1/5e2e/click.png

Every "click" should show a different table. In jsFiddle the colored boxes are only for example of a table, you know?

Comment: Better examples...

**Example 1:** http://justpic.info/images1/87be/click.png
**Example 2:** http://justpic.info/images1/211e/click2.png

Comment: But your pictures show what is happening in the fiddle? The fiddle is correct? If not, how not?

Comment: The fiddle is correct, but if you try it to put in the homepage (just download it), it won't work. :(

Comment: Here is the original homepage. I only added all the fiddle-stuff... no chance. The page jumps up only, if you click on the "click"-links... http://ge.tt/2itz9FC1/v/0?c

Comment: Honestly, I can't upload all this onto a sever and then try everything out, i simply don't have the time - what errors are you gettingin the console?

Comment: You don't have to upload anything. Just download the 4 MB and open the the index.html with firefox. The homepage works fine. No errors in console. Only the new jQuery stuff does not work. there is already some other jQuery in that homepage and that works fine.

Comment: there is nothing to click under the dates under the dials - on the screen shot it says click - there is nothing in your homepage that says click or even anything to click - you must upload to a server so i can see it in action or I will have to leave it, taking up way too much time i'm afraid and have paid work to do, happy to help as always but this is getting nowhere really, it has to be on a server so can see it in action

Answer (score 1):

Have a list of names all with class e.g. `.names`

Set `.names` to `display:none`

Give rookies class `.rookie`, amateurs `.amateur` etc.

Use jquery click to filter, so when click .amateurs `$('.amateur').show();`

Click show all `$('.names').show();`

Is this what you mean? I haven't coded as I'm not totally sure what you want to do.

CODE:

Basically it's this, v simple stuff (also added IDs to tabs which are clickable):

```
$( "#rookies" ).click(function() {
    $('.name').hide();
    $('.rookie').show();
});
$( "#amateurs" ).click(function() {
    $('.name').hide();
    $('.amateur').show();
});
$( "#showAll" ).click(function() {
    $('.name').show();
});
```

[See it working here](http://jsfiddle.net/darrensw/TepJS/8/)

Comment: That should work for me, yes. Some code examples at JSFiddle would be great, so I can modify them.

Comment: Added code and fiddle to answer

Comment: Thank you very much. That's how I want it.

Comment: Hmm, on my machine it does not work. It always shows all names, doesn't matter which button I click. In JSfiddle no problem, it works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/TepJS/10/

I put the JavaScript in my header. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure, have a look at this, just streamlined the code http://jsfiddle.net/darrensw/TepJS/11/

Comment: Have you looked in the console to see any errors? What's the URL of the page?

Comment: I am working locale. But it should work, because it worked before, too. How do check the errors (debug)?

Comment: use firefox, hit F12 then reload your page, there is a console at the bottom of the browser

Comment: I updated the first post completely. Maybe someone can help now.